# How to update object in vuex store array?

Tags: arrays, vuex, store

I'm pretty new to vue/vuex/vuetify but starting to get the hang of it.
I have a problem though I haven't been able to solve properly.

I have an array of "projects" in my store. When deleting and adding items to the store via mutations the changes reflect properly in subcomponents referencing the array as a property.

However, changes to items in the array does not reflect even though I can see that the array in the store is updated.

The only way I got it to "work" with an update action was to either :

1. remove the project from the array in the store and then add it
2. use code that sort of does exactly the same as described above but like so:

   ```
   state.categories = [
   ...state.categories.filter(element => element.id !== id),
   category
   ]
   ```

But the problem with the above two methods is that the order of the array gets changed and I would really like to avoid that..

So basically, how would I rewrite my mutation method below to make the state reflect to subcomponents and keep the order of the array?

```
 updateProject(state, project) {

        var index = state.projects.findIndex(function (item, i) {
            return item.id === project.id;
        });

        state.projects[index] = project;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` to inject edited project in correct position:

```
updateProject(state, project) {

  var index = state.projects.findIndex(function(item, i) {
    return item.id === project.id;
  });

  state.projects = [
    ...state.projects.slice(0, index),
    project,
    ...state.projects.slice(index + 1)
  ]
}
```

or you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` to make a deep copy of object

```
updateProject(state, project) {

  var index = state.projects.findIndex(function(item, i) {
    return item.id === project.id;
  });

  state.projects[index] = project;
  state.projects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.projects))
}
```